# How to do a Venn Diagramm with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group_final = c("EUR", "MAT_EUR", "MAT_Top_EUR", "Top_EUR", "MAT", "MAT_Top", "Top"),
  count = c(17744, 69, 63, 104, 517, 34, 819)
)
```

I would like to plot a Venn Diagram with three main circles, represented by EUR, MAT, and Top, while the intersections of these three circles are called Top_EUR, MAT_Top, MAT_EUR, MAT_Top_EUR. How can I do this Venn Diagram with ggplot2?

Comment: Have you tried the  [ggvenn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggvenn/readme/README.html) or [ggVennDiagram](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggVennDiagram/readme/README.html) packages? Where did you get stuck?